# Google Forms custom script nowhere to be found but still working

Tags: forms, email, scripting

I created a form and added some HTML using the script editor to send a confirmation email to the person filling out the form. It was working great but I needed to change some info in the confirmation email and now there are no scripts under script editor and no history. The weird thing is the script seems to still be working and even follows my forms - I created a completely new form (not copy/paste). Has anyone run into this issue or have any ideas on how to resolve it?